# Print version of TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have following tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "version": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and looking at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html --version flat should print version of TypeScript but it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--version` is one of several special-purpose options that only works on the command line, not in `tsconfig.json`.  It makes the compiler print the version *instead* of compiling your code, so having the option permanently enabled in `tsconfig.json` wouldn't be very useful anyway.